# Use off() inside event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
    $("#selector").on("someevent", function(){
        let variable = some_value;
        $("#anotherselector").click(function(){
            //code involving variable here
            if(condition){
                $(this).off(reference to click event here); 
            }   
        });
    });
});
```

Is there any way to turn off an event from inside its handler? I'm trying to do something like the code above, and I need it to turn off ONLY that specific click event (each click event is different).

Comment: Instead of turning it off, why don't you just have it do nothing when that condition is met? in other words, do something when that condition is not met

Comment: I don't want to have multiple events that do nothing. After the condition is true, if it turns false again, it would break the code (as in it could possibly end up causing two event listeners to be created for one element).

Comment: So you want to unbind the click event right? Have you read the off documentation? http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: You are nesting an event  inside of an event that is attached with `on`. So when you call `$(this)` are you expecting the `#selector`? or `#anotherselector?` I suspect that's the cause of your issue

Comment: I expect it to refer to $(#anotherselector).

Comment: There are examples in the off documentation on how to do this

Comment: @Huangism I did read the documentation but I don't know how to do remove it for the specific event where the condition is true.

Comment: I have 2 suspicions. 1) `this` is not being scoped properly due to 3-way nesting. 2) this is a click event so there is the effect of event bubbling maybe the propogation is being screwy somewhere. Removing the event should be possible

Comment: You need to clarify this a bit. Is the condition already set when `someevent` fires? or does it set later? What code have you tried? if you read the documentation you should know how to unbind this already. What is the actual problem you are experiencing when unbinding

Comment: Every time someevent happens, it adds a click event which is different from every other click event because there is a variable that is set outside of the click event inside the somevent event which is used by the click event. This is why I can't just remove all of the click events from another selector.

Comment: Add a namespace to each of the different click event and you can remove the click by namespace. If you can give an example of your multiple click event(2 is enough) to reproduce the issue, this would be a lot easier to answer

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference the click event, you can simply pass it `'click'` and the selector for which to disable the event:

```
$(function(){
    $("#selector").on("someevent", function(){
        $("#anotherselector").click(function(){
            if(condition){
                $('#anotherselector').off('click'); 
            }   
        });
    });
});
```

```js
let numHandler = 0;
$('#register').click(function () {
  let counter = 0;
  let num = ++numHandler;
  $('#clickme').click(function handler () {
    counter++;
    console.log(`Handler ${num} clicked!`);
    if (counter == 3) $('#clickme').off('click', handler);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickme">Click me!</button>
<button id="register">Register new handler</button>
```

You can read more about the off function [in the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: I think this is correct. Events should not be nested in other event's like OP was approaching jQuery is slightly less call-back dependant than vanilla and should be used accordingly.

Comment: I didn't accept the answer because it deletes all click events and not the specific one. Each click event is different because of a variable that is declared in someevent and used in the click event. The variable changes value in the someevent so each click event is different.